# WinXp - Using GPO to set a home page for everyone

Tags: internet-explorer, group-policy, homepage

I've change the "Important URL's" in the "Internet Explorer" part of the gpo to the home page I want to set, and I did also Enable the "Disable home page changing" for the gpo.

It did disable the "Home page changing" ability for everyone, but the home page didn't change at all.

Comment: GPO = Group policy object?

Comment: Yes, was I supposed to ask this in ServerFault.com?

Comment: In the important URLs section, you said you customized the home page URL, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go there:

- User Configuration - Windows Settings - Internet Explorer Maintenance - URLs/Important URLs

Set: Home Page URL to your prefered URL.

Don't set Search bar URL and Online Support page URL.

Scope: Authenticated Users
Enforce your GPO and then... Et voila!

It should be good as long as you set it to USERS and not to Computers.

Comment: The part of forcing to users and not only to computers was missing for me, thanks.

Comment: Anytime my friend!